# Can't input text inside a modal displayed over a dialog

Tags: reactjs, antd

#### Reproduction link

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Click on open dialog
2. Click on open popup
3. Try to enter any text. You won't be able to able the text inside popup fields.

#### What is expected?

I should be able to enter text inside input field in the popup.

#### What is actually happening?

When the `antd popup` is opened inside a dialog, I am able to see the popup by changin `z-index` but I am not able to enter anything inside popup.

`EnvironmentInfo`
antd    3.13.6
React   v16.4.1
System  mac os 10.14.2
Browser reactjs v16.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change your Dialog to:

```
        <Dialog
          fullScreen
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          TransitionComponent={Transition}
          disableEnforceFocus={true}
        >
```

This should fix the issue.